# Codeigniter e-mail problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made a new website, and I have the following problem: when I try to send an email from the website, it give me an error, but the message sent successfully to the email

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/73/8079773/html/system/language/arabic/email_lang.php:1)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 671
```

What am I missing here? By the way I'm using codeigniter framework and the email was sent successfully from my localhost machine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the email that is being sent. Are you redirecting the user afterward? Can you post your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have ***NO*** whitespace before `<?php` opening tag in your arabic `email_lang.php` file.

Comment: Finally , you r right there was whitespace before <?php i think i must check my arabic 'email_lang.php' thanks problem solved

Answer (score 2):

What this means is that you are trying to modify the headers more than once. You cannot have ANY markup sent to the browser before specific headers are sent or else you will receive this error and the headers will not post properly.

Line 671 in libraries/Session.php is most likely sending headers to the browser, but you probably have the call to this file AFTER markup is sent to the browser. Make sure you are including libraries/Session.php before anything is posted to the browser.

more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: OK So why this only happen when i try to send the email from the web host but when i try to send it from the local machine it work fine?

Comment: Your local machine may not have error handling turned on. When you send it through the remote host it may be outputting an error. If an error is printed, you cannot do a header redirect.

Comment: mmm , but my local machine's error handling is turned on , anyway i will consider this , thanks for your help ....

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you are outputting something onto the page, which is not allowing the header redirect to happen. If you are not printing/echoing anything, make sure the script is not resulting in any errors being printed out, as this will cause the same result.